# Is there a way to hide a page redirect or refresh from Google's page speed algorithm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagespeed

I'm trying to hide content from Google's page speed algorithm. Is this possible? At the moment, it seems google takes into account settimeout and basic refresh functions. Is there a more obscure way of achieving this?

Regards.

Comment: render the page 10 seconds later.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post code and effort

Comment: At least post a link to the site!